# Cholov Yisroel formula

Tags: kashrut-kosher, product-recommendation, chalav-yisrael-jewishmilk

Where in the world can there be found producers of the cholov yisroel formula (except Materna that does not ship to north America & US where, they don't like to ship and the Kenda from england) ?

Does France has Cholov Yisroel formula producers?

Thanks.

Comment: Not quite what you're seeking, but they make dairy free baby formula for kids with allergies

Comment: This document shows it per brand. https://www.kashrut.com/consumer/dairy/Cholov_Yisrael.pdf                                          
But I agree with what Double AA writes; What exactly do you want to know?

Comment: Do you want to access it in America?

Answer (score 1):

Your question is a little unclear. Where would you need it shipped to?

Materna is widely available in Lakewood, NJ stores as is Kendamill ([Aisle 9](https://aisle9market.com/lakewood/#!?q=formula), [Kosher West](https://www.kosherwest.com/search/formula) Gourmet Glatt - I tried to linking the page with the formulas). Maybe some would ship it if you call. I also found Materna on some westcoast kosher supermarket websites in the past.

Answer (score 1):

Materna is pretty widespread but there is also on the market a make produced by Nature's One's called [Baby's Only® Cholov Yisroel Formula](https://www.naturesone.com/babys-only-cholov-yisroel-dairy-formula/) (for toddlers, age 1 and up) which is available in the States and is shipped abroad in [certain countries](https://www.naturesone.com/global-distribution/)

Answer (score 1):

Similac makes a Cholov Yisroel formula. They call it Similac lamehadrin. [https://www.amazon.com/Similac-Lamehadrin-Badatz-certified-Advance-Certified/dp/B07BF4KTSY](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07BF4KTSY)

There is also kendamil https://kendamil.com/collections/classic-formula/products/classic-first-infant-milk. The link is to the UK website but I know my local American store sells it